# $dS^d$ and $AdS^d$ are conformally equivalent

Tags: gravity, differential-geometry, anti-de-sitter-spacetime, de-sitter-spacetime

I have seen in the book by Zee (Einstein Gravity in a Nutshell) the following metric for $dS^4$:

$ds^2 = \frac{1}{\cos^2 \tau} \big( - d\tau^2 + d\psi^2 + \sin^2 \psi \, d\Omega_2^2 \big) $,

(Eq. IX.10.43, page 638), where $\tau \in [- \frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ and $\psi \in [0, \pi]$, and the following metric for $AdS^4$:

$ ds^2 = \frac{1}{\cos^2 \psi} \big( - dt^2 + d\psi^2 + \sin^2 \psi \,  d\Omega_2^2 \big)  $,

(Eq. IX.11.12, page 654) where $t \in (- \infty, + \infty)$ and $\psi \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$.

I understand how to get these expressions and their meaning (I think). And I understand that they are not globally equal because of the different domains of each variable. But does this have any consequences or interpretation? I mean, are $dS^d$ and $AdS^d$ the same thing, in some coordinate system, up to size?

Answer (score 1):

An AdS spacetime and a dS spacetime have scalar curvature of opposite sign. This difference cannot be transformed away by a conformal relationship since two metrics, $g_{\mu\nu}$ and $\tilde{g}_{\mu\nu}$ say, are conformally equivalent if we can write

$$
ds^2 = \Lambda^2\,d\tilde{s}^2 \,,
$$
where $\Lambda\,\equiv\,\Lambda(x^{\mu})$ is a function of the spacetime co-ordinates. Since $\Lambda^2$ appears on the right hand side and it is positive, the spacetimes with metrics $g_{\mu\nu}$ and $\tilde{g}_{\mu\nu}$ yield scalar curvatures that have the same sign.

Edit(20/01/2019)
I think a definite way to determine whether or not the two metrics quoted from Zee's book are conformally equivalent is to calculate their Weyl tensors since the Weyl tensor is invariant under conformal transformations. (See, for example, the appendix (possibly A.14) discussing the behaviour of the Ricci tensor and other objects under conformal transformations in ``Black Hole Physics: Basic Concepts and New Developments", Valeri P. Frolov & Igor D. Novikov, 1998, Kluwer Academic Publishing).

Comment: But the question makes it clear, assuming it is correct, that dS and AdS are, in fact, locally conformally equivalent, so how do we get different curvatures? Where is the mistake?

Comment: The two metrics have the same form and kind of look the same, but what is the relationship between the co-ordinates $t, \tau\,,$ and $\psi\,$ when going from one metric to the other. I think that therein lies the difference. I don’t have time to do the calculations and find the relationship between these co-ordinates.

Comment: So, I don’t think the two metrics are conformally equivalent.

Comment: I know $dS$ and $AdS$ have different curvature, but the way I have written the metric you have indeed a conformal factor $\Lambda^2 = \frac{\cos^2 \psi}{\cos^2 \tau} > 0 $ (or the other way around).

Comment: Well, I remember now: a conformal transformation doesn't necessarily preserve the sign of the curvature scalar. It's a complicated formula, and the sign can change.

Comment: Really @Javier? Where can I find that explained?

Comment: @MBolin: see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulas_in_Riemannian_geometry#Under_a_conformal_change). You can see that the transformation of $R$ is pretty complicated and it involves the Laplacian of the conformal factor; you can get more or less anything you want with a suitable transformation. At the very least, $R$ can certainly change sign.

Comment: @ Javier: So if the scalar Ricci curvature can change sign by a conformal transformation how can this be physical?

Comment: @ MBolin: If you say that $\frac{\cos^2\psi}{\cos^2\tau}$ is the conformal factor I think there is still problem with identifying the relationship between $t\,, \tau$ and $\psi\,.$

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: OK, nice. I have computed that he Weyl tensor is zero , both for $dS$ and $AdS$, in any dimension. Now I'd like to be sure that this means conformal equivalence. Zee says that if two metrics are conformally related, their Weyl tensor is equal, and then he says that this can be used to test for conformal flatness (VI.1, exercise 15). You think it is a sufficient condition? I mean, if the Weyl tensor is zero for $dS$, $AdS$ (and of course flat space), then they are all conformally equivalent? Or is it just a necessary condition?

Comment: Wikipedia says it is that in dimensions $d \geq 4$ it is a sufficient condition (for $d<4$ you have to look at the Cotton tensor).